# SQL join multiple tables from multiple database connections

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I've been searching on this issue for 2 days with no luck so I guess it's time to make a question; I know this has been asked before, but nothing that I've found has been able to solve my issue. I have two tables from two different database connections that I want to perform a join on. So far I have:

```
$conn1 = odbc_connect("db-1","user","pass")
        or die ("Couldn't Connect to Server");

$conn2 = odbc_connect("db-2","user","pass")
        or die ("Couldn't Connect to Server");

$Query = 'SELECT PV_Job1.PlantCode,
       PV_Job1.JobCode, 
       PV_Jobline1.JobLineNum,
       PV_Jobline1.ItemCode,
       PM_Item1.ItemShortDesc

FROM VISION.PUB.PV_Job PV_Job1 

LEFT OUTER JOIN spec.public.specification specification
    ON PV_JobLine1.ItemCode=specification.customer_item_code

LEFT OUTER JOIN VISION.PUB.PV_Jobline PV_Jobline1
    ON (PV_Job1.CompNum=PV_JobLine1.CompNum
    AND PV_Job1.PlantCode=PV_JobLine1.PlantCode)
    AND PV_Job1.JobCode=PV_JobLine1.JobCode';

$Result = odbc_exec($conn1,$Query);
```

which throws an error. Other answers to this question have recommended using something like server1.database1.dbo.table1, but what would server1 and database1 be in this case? I'm pretty new to SQL and I've never done anything like this. I also tried creating a linked server which didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see in your code where you use connection 2.

To make this simpler, let's focus on this code in your SQL Server. Open up SQL Server Management Studio and connect to your database.

To write this query, you need a linked server. You should be able to create this in Management Studio. You'll need a user on the `db-2` database, and then you can create a linked server on `db-1` that uses that user's credentials to login in. When you run a query over the linked server, it will use this user's credentials, so please make sure it has `db_datareader` permissions level on the linked database.

In your question, you state that it didn't work. We need the error you're seeing when you try to use the linked server.

server1.database1.dbo.table1 is a reference to a linked server. When you use the fourth part of the name, server1, you're referring to a connection to your linked server.

Comment: I use it in the first join. "spec" is an object in the second database. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the SQL server itself. This also means I don't have access to the error logs. So the only way to make this work is if I create a link in SQL Server Management?

Comment: Yes, if I'm understanding your question correctly. I want to clarify one thing: in SQL Server, databases are hosted on an instance. One instance is what you connect to, and from there you query the databases on it. For example, the server name often is the same as the instance name, and contains the name of the environment, such as `SPECPROD` or `SPECDEV`. Within `SPECDEV`, you would have multiple databases, such as `spec_archive`, `spec` etc. Are you trying to write a query across multiple servers or across databases on one server?

Comment: Not entirely sure, the only visual I have of the setup is in Crystal Reports, and here they are listed as two separate connections. I.e. the first one is PostgreSpec->spec->public->specification and the second one is Vision-LIVE->VISION->PUB->PV_Job, with PostgreSpec and Vision-LIVE being separate connections.

Comment: I made a mistake by assuming this was SQL Server. I think your question is too specific to your environment for me to provide a solution, but I think you'll be able to solve it if you can contact a DBA or the person who set up these connections. Sorry if I confused you, but it looks like you could be using Postgre SQL as your Database Management System (DBMS) instead of SQL Server. I assumed from the linked server and the tag that it was SQL Server (a Microsoft DBMS).

Comment: That would be my mistake, like I said I don't have much experience with SQL and I wasn't aware of this. Thanks for the attempt.